# Website access with Python: Internal error

Tags: python, urllib

In my program, I need to access a website html and extract some French postal codes.

When I do this in my browser it is working, but when I try to access it with Python I can't stop having an internal error HTTP 500

Do you think it is the website blocking access or is it my program problem?
Thanks

Below is my code:

```
import requests
import urllib
import re

link = "https://annuaire.118712.fr/magasin/mcdonald-s_1"
f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
myfile = f.read()
for result in re.findall(r"postalCode\": \"(\d{5})", str(myfile)):
    print(result)
```

And below is the error I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-76fbd165889e> in <module>
      5 
      6 link = "https://annuaire.118712.fr/magasin/mcdonald-s_1"
----> 7 f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
      8 myfile = f.read()
      9 for result in re.findall(r"postalCode\": \"(\d{5})", str(myfile)):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    561             http_err = 0
    562         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
--> 563         result = self._call_chain(*args)
    564         if result:
    565             return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    753         fp.close()
    754 
--> 755         return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
    756 
    757     http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: It's not a program error it means the site is not reachable or down at the moment try after somtime.

Comment: Thanks @Deepan But it is strange as I can access it with my browser... Are you sure it is not a blocking point from the website?

Comment: I can't able to access it shows `MINCE ALORS !!!`

Answer (score 0):

use requests library instead urllib is more friendly.
That code works fine:

```
import requests
import re

link = "https://annuaire.118712.fr/magasin/mcdonald-s_1"
response = requests.get(url=link)
if response.ok:
    data = response.text

    for result in re.findall(r"postalCode\": \"(\d{5})", data):
        print(result)
else:
    print("Http Error: "+str(response.status_code))
    exit(1)
```

Results:

01170
01700
01300
01800
01210
01200
01170
01700
01330
01000
01440
01000
01000
01500
01100
01300
01300
01300
01170
01710

Comment: Your original code works too btw

Comment: Thanks but it is strange, it still not works for me...Neither mine or yours. :-O